# MySQL - select query- only show multiple connections

Tags: mysql, select

i have this schema: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9cd727/2

i only want to see the job_id's with 2 or more double-connected user_id's

in the schema-example: only job_id=1 has 2x user_id=2 connected
so i need only to know in select-result the job_id 1

any idea for a select-query???

Comment: Please consider to read the article "how to ask" of SO: stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT job_id, user_id, COUNT(user_id) FROM mission GROUP BY job_id, user_id HAVING COUNT(user_id) > 1
```